# How to reset Windows 8.1 icons?

Tags: windows-8.1, icons

I few weeks ago I had installed windows 8.1 on mu ASUS system and recently I discovered that the my system icons have been changed to these. can any one of please tell me how to fix it.

[Screenshot](http://s9.postimg.org/ud6b1sjgu/Untitled.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8.1 can alter fonts (to icons also), based on your input language settings.

So first, check input language and make sure it's default.

Then, open a command prompt. Enter the command `shell:fonts` to open the Windows-Fonts folder.

Click the Text  **"Font settings"**. Click the button "**Restore default font settings**" 
This also removes all manual changes that you've made to your display settings.

Then, delete C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\IconCache.db.
That is the icon cache.

To delete it, open a command prompt, end 'explorer' process, delete the file.
The process will reload automatically. If it does not, just type 'explorer' into the command prompt and it will load it back.

Comment: Overmind, thanks for the reply but it didn't work.